# Parallel matrix inversion with gridMathematica

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying to test parallel symbolic matrix inversion on cluster with gridMathematica
`7.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 18, 2009)`.
I use next commands:

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["node1",2]]  //Out: {KernelObject[11, node1],  KernelObject[12, node1]}
data=Import["/home/myhome/500.txt", "Table"]; //square 500x500 matrix with integers
m = ToExpression[data];
Parallelize[a = Inverse[m]];
```

But it issue next error:

```
Parallelize::nopar1:
a = Inverse[m] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential
 evaluation
```

What's wrong with my commands? How can I evaluate symbolic matrix inversion on cluster with multiple nodes?

Comment: Are you really, really sure that you want to compute the inverse symbolically? What do you expect to see afterwards? In general, what you attempt is a very, very,_very_ bad thing to do (both symbolically and numerically). That's why nobody would ever implement a parallel matrix inversions...

Comment: The message says it all. Symbolic `Inverse` has no code to support computing it by parallelized kernels.